# linux remove files in a directory except symlinks?

Tags: linux, bash

In linux, how can I remove all the files in a directory except the files that are actually symlinks to files in other directories?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Linux & Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I got great answers. Please feel free to move to "Linux & Unix" if needed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `find` command:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -delete
```

`-type f` will ensure you only delete files not symlinks

Comment: This also leaves directories, fifos, sockets, as well as symlinks.

Comment: @Jens True, however it was not clear from OP's question if he wanted to remove directories. If he wants to remove everything except symlinks then `find /path/to/dir ! -type l -delete` should work.

Comment: What if you want to keep some extensions, but not others? Like delete all .txt and .doc files but keep .sh